# How to run management command in test file on Travis?

Tags: django, travis-ci

In one of my test files I call a Django management command:

```
def setUpModule():
    management.call_command('loaddata', 'frontend/fixtures/chemicals.json',
                            verbosity=0)
    management.call_command('create_indexes_and_matviews',
                            db_name, db_user, db_pass,
                            verbosity=2)
```

This test runs fine when I run it locally with `manage.py test`.

However, on Travis I get this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpModule (frontend.tests.test_api_views)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/.../frontend/tests/test_api_views.py", line 35, in setUpModule
    verbosity=2)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 95, in call_command
    raise CommandError("Unknown command: %r" % name)
CommandError: Unknown command: 'create_indexes_and_matviews'
```

How can I let Travis know about the command?

This is my Travis file:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
addons:
  postgresql: "9.3"
env:
  - SECRET_KEY=test DB_NAME=dbtest DB_USER=test DB_PASS=test
before_install:
  - export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=....settings.local
  - export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/builds/...
install:
 - pip install -r requirements.txt
 - pip install -r requirements/local.txt
before_script:
 - psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE dbtest;'
 - psql -U postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis" -d dbtest
 - psql -U postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology" -d dbtest
 - psql -U postgres -c "CREATE USER test WITH CREATEUSER PASSWORD 'test';"
 - psql -U postgres -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dbtest to test;"
 - psql -U postgres -c "ALTER USER test CREATEDB;"
 - cd frontend && python manage.py migrate
script:
 - python manage.py test
```

Is there something I should add so that it knows where to find management commands?

Comment: Why is the path to the settings module `....settings.local`? How does your folder structure looks like?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the Two Scoops of Django layout https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/tree/develop/project_name/project_name/settings So I have a settings folder with `local.py`, `production.py` etc. I think the ellipsis is just because it's copied and pasted. I don't think the settings file is the problem, because Travis runs everything fine if I exclude the management command.

Comment: Do you use a different settings file on travis than the one you use locally?

Comment: No - I use the `local.py`, file which is the same as the one I use locally.

Comment: Can we get a link to your actual code? If possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my practice I know two reasons for such problem.

**A.** No `the_app` with `create_indexes_and_matviews` listed in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` (it could be missed, excluded in if/else or try/except magic)

To check actual settings, try to add following command to the Travis file

```
echo "from django.conf import settings;print(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)" |  python manage.py shell
```

**B.** Missed app dependencies. Try to get the actual error on travis with following command:

```
echo "from the_app.management.commands.create_indexes_and_matviews import Command" |  python manage.py shell
```

Usually, real import error is descriptive enough to find the fix.